# Override when creating new object

Tags: c#, .net

Can I do something like this in C#?

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator()
{
    protected override int ValueOfK() 
    {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

If so, how do you do it?

Comment: That's not possible. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Just curious: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Exactly what you wrote in question - no. But if you would give reason, there may be workaround.

Answer (score 3):

In order to override a method, you need to inherit from `Calculator` and override the `ValueOfK` method in the inheriting class (provided it was declared as `virtual` in `Calculator`).

There is no other mechanism to override methods in C#.

```
public Calculator
{
    protected virtual int ValueOfK() 
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public NewKCalculator : Calculator
{
    protected override int ValueOfK() 
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the method is non-virtual or static you need to use `new` keyword instead of `override`.

Comment: @Zen - That would be _shadowing_ and not inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a `JavaScript`. You can not *attach* methods to already defined type at run-time.

You can use [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) to achieve the *similiar* functionality in `C#`.
But, basically, I would suggest to avoid that. It's better to revise architecture, then make use of dynamic stuff, if it's possible naturally. Let's continue benefit from static type language goodness.

Comment: To be fair, Java (much closer to C# than Javascript) also has this ability, via anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't know java, so made a note on the language that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method (**EDIT**: if the `Calculator` does not implement `ValueOfK()`)  (More info : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) )

```
 Calculator calc = new Calculator();
 int val=calc.ValueOfK();
```

Extension:

```
public static class MyExtension
{
    public static int ValueOfK(this Calculator calc)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Otherwise as **Oded** mentioned already you need to inherit from `Calculator` and override the `ValueOfK`. If the method is `non-virtual` or `static` you need to use `new` keyword:

```
public class Calculator
{
    protected int ValueOfK()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public class BetterCalculator : Calculator
{
    protected new int ValueOfK()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately extension methods cannot override instance methods.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Yes, I made a mistake. Inheritance is the only solution.